# Facebook Prophet on non-daily data doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting, facebook-prophet

I have data sampled every 15 minutes. I have trained the model (default options) and what concerns me is the fact that when I make a forecast, it seems that the model does not work so well. In the image below, no spikes are predicted and it seems like I can't see the intraday seasonality.
Do you have any suggestions?
[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [ask] and then try to produce a [mcve].

Comment: Anyway it's possible to add custom seasonalities [doc](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/seasonality,_holiday_effects,_and_regressors.html#specifying-custom-seasonalities)